# Responsive Borders

Tags: javascript, css

I created a JavaScript function which captures an elements' width and assigns a percentage of that measurement to the element's border-width style. Everything works fine except that when I enlarge the window beyond a certain point the last element drops down to the next line as if there were not enough room for it above. I'm using box-sizing: border-box and vw's for my measurements and everything adds up to 100vw so I can't figure out why the last element is dropping down to the next line. I tested this code outside of CodePen and all the elements stayed on one line, so it could be just a CodePen problem. I'm just curious if there is something I am missing.

Here is a link to the code:
http://codepen.io/CASEYJAYMARTIN/pen/GrEaI

Comment: Sounds like it's a codepen problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm getting the same "problem" locally too.

Comment: May be border width is increasing total width of box

Answer (score 0):

I set up your example locally, and I experienced the problem you described whereby the last box dropped onto the next line. I think my scrollbar was the culprit.

```
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I hid it and now all the boxes are on one line.

Also, you might want to floor your `borderWidth`.

```
borderWidth = Math.floor(squareWidth * 0.1);
```

Also, don't forget to support Firefox.

```
.box, .square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: You were right. It was the scrollbar that was the real problem. I've updated the code to a % based width, which excludes the scrollbar, and it appears to be working fine.